# how do I extract keys from a JSON object?

Tags: json, splunk

My splunk instance queries a database once an hour for data about products, and gets a JSON string back that is structured like this:

```
{"counts":
    {"green":413,
     "red":257,
     "total":670,
     "product_list":
        { "urn:product:1":{ 
            "name":"M & Ms" ,
            "total":332 ,
            "green":293 ,
            "red":39 } ,
          "urn:product:2":{ 
            "name":"Christmas Ornaments" ,
            "total":2 ,
            "green":0 ,
            "red":2 } ,
         "urn:product:3":{ 
            "name":"Traffic Lights" ,
            "total":1 ,
            "green":0 ,
            "red":1 } ,
         "urn:product:4":{ 
            "name":"Stop Signs" ,
            "total":2 ,
            "green":0 ,
            "red":2 },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have a query that alerts when the counts.green drops by 10% over 24 hours:

```
index=database_catalog source=RedGreenData | head 1 
| spath path=counts.green output=green_now
| table green_now
| join host
    [| search index=database_catalog source=RedGreenData latest=-1d | head 1 | spath path=counts.green output=green_yesterday
    | table green_yesterday]
| where green_yesterday > 0
| eval delta=(green_yesterday - green_now)/green_yesterday * 100 
| where delta > 10
```

While I'm an experienced developer in C, C++, Java, SQL, JavaScript, and several others, I'm fairly new to Splunk's Search Processing Language, and references and tutorials seem pretty light, at least the ones I've found.

My next story is to at least expose all the individual products, and identify which ones have a 10% drop over 24 hours.

I thought a reasonable learning exercise would be to extract the names of all the products, and eventually turn that into a table with name, product code (e.g. urn:product:4), green count today, green count 24 hours ago, and then filter that on a 10% drop for all products where yesterday's count is positive.  And I'm stuck.  The references to {} are all for a JSON array [], not a JSON object with keys and values.

I'd love to get a table out that looks something like this:

| ID | Name | Green | Red | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| urn:product:1 | M & Ms | 293 | 39 | 332 |
| urn:product:2 | Christmas Ornaments | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| urn:product:3 | Traffic Lights | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| urn:product:4 | Stop Signs | 0 | 2 | 2 |

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think produces the output you want:

```
| spath
| table counts.product_list.*
| transpose
| rex field=column "counts.product_list.(?<ID>[^.]*).(?<fieldname>.*)"
| fields - column
| xyseries ID fieldname "row 1"
| table ID name green red total
```

1. use `transpose` to get the field names as data
2. use `rex` to extract the ID and the field name
3. use `xyseries` to pivot the data into the output

Here is a run-anywhere example using your source data:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="
{\"counts\":
    {\"green\":413,
     \"red\":257,
     \"total\":670,
     \"product_list\":
        { \"urn:product:1\":{ 
            \"name\":\"M & Ms\" ,
            \"total\":332 ,
            \"green\":293 ,
            \"red\":39 } ,
          \"urn:product:2\":{ 
            \"name\":\"Christmas Ornaments\" ,
            \"total\":2 ,
            \"green\":0 ,
            \"red\":2 } ,
         \"urn:product:3\":{ 
            \"name\":\"Traffic Lights\" ,
            \"total\":1 ,
            \"green\":0 ,
            \"red\":1 } ,
         \"urn:product:4\":{ 
            \"name\":\"Stop Signs\" ,
            \"total\":2 ,
            \"green\":0 ,
            \"red\":2 },
        }
    }
}"
| spath
| table counts.product_list.*
| transpose
| rex field=column "counts.product_list.(?<ID>[^.]*).(?<fieldname>.*)"
| fields - column
| xyseries ID fieldname "row 1"
| table ID name green red total
```

Comment: Thank you Jerry!  That gets me a lot further.  I need to study the individual commands to better understand how you put it all together.  One issue I have right now is that I get the ID, but the name, red, green, and total rows are doubled.

Comment: It turns out the spath section of the query is unnecessary, and causes odd duplications when the actual data is more than 5,000 characters.  So I'm going to use index=myIndex source=mySource | head 1 | table counts.product_list.* | transpose | rex field=column "counts.product_list.(?<ID>[^.]*).(?<fieldname>.*)" | fields - column | xyseries ID fieldname "row 1" | table ID name visible invisible total.

Comment: @ChrisWood  Your splunk must be automatically extracting the data from the json if `counts.product_list` exists in your index.  So for you, extracting the json again just messes things up. I am glad you got it working.

Comment: For posterity, one of our local Splunk experts recommended resolving the duplication issue by changing the '| xyseries ID fieldname "row 1"' line to: '| rename "row 1" as row1
| eval row1=mvdedup(row1)
| xyseries ID fieldname row1'